# Rails 4 - Unpermitted parameters for nested param despite whitelisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, strong-parameters

I have two models `user_item` and `user_item_images`.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "user_item_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "picture"
  end

  create_table "user_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "status",          default: 0
    t.boolean  "hide_banner",     default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.string   "declined_reason"
  end
```

I have a form where the user should submit a new `user_item`.  The only field in the form is for pictures where the user can upload multiple pictures.  On success, a single new `user_item` is created along with a new `user_item_image` for each picture that is uploaded.

**form**

```
    <%= simple_form_for :user_item, url: user_items_path, html: {multipart: true} do |user_item_builder| %>
      <%= user_item_builder.input :item_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "#{@item.id}" } %>
      <%= user_item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_item_images do |user_item_images_builder| %>
        <%= user_item_images_builder.input :picture, as: :file, label: false, name: "user_item_images[picture][]", input_html: { multiple: true } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**user_item_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user_item = current_user.user_items.new(user_item_params)
    raise 'foo'
    if @user_item.save
      params[:user_item][:user_item_images]['picture'].each do |a|
        @user_item_image = @user_item.user_item_images.create!(:picture => a)
      end
      # Sends email to user when item request is created.
      itemMailer.user_item_submission_email(current_user, @user_item.item).deliver_later

      flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your item request!"
    else
      @user_item.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        flash[:alert] = message
      end
    end

    redirect_to item_path(@user_item.item)
  end

  private 

  def user_item_params
    params.require(:user_item).permit(:item_id, user_item_images_attributes: [:user_item_id, :picture])
  end
```

**user_item.rb**

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_item_images
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_item_images
```

**user_item_image.rb**

```
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :user_item
```

When I submit the form I get `Unpermitted parameter: user_item_images` in the console and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    <%= ..., name: "user_item_images[picture][]", ... %>
```

to this:

```
    <%= ..., name: "user_item_images_attributes[picture][]", ... %>
```

Comment: I made the change and my html looks like this `<input multiple="multiple" class="file required" type="file" name="user_item[user_item_images][picture][]" id="user_item_user_item_images_picture">`.  Shouldn't it be different?

Comment: Ah needed to change the syntax as I'm using simple_form

Comment: Do I even need to whitelist this since I am just using params to create the user_item_picture objects?

Comment: You are using `params` (via `user_item_params`) on the first line of `#create` to create a `UserItem`, which also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_item_images`. That's what is causing the error messages and why you need to whitelist `user_item_images_attributes`.

Comment: The reason you needed to change the `input`'s `name` is because `accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo` looks for the values inside `params[:foo_attributes]`, not `params[:foo]`.

Comment: It looks like you'd better change `params[:user_item][:user_item_images]['picture'].each do |a|` to `:user_item_images_attributes` also.

Comment: Or actually that whole loop should be unnecessary now that you've got the correct key. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will take care of it.

Comment: When I add images to the form and submit (with `raise 'foo'` left in the create action to trigger the webconsole) I type `user_item_params` and it just returns `=> {"item_id"=>"3"}`.  Is this behavior correct?  Shouldn't it be showing a hash of the files to be uploaded?  Typing params on the other hand will return a `user_item` hash and a `user_item_images_attributes` hash.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `simple_form`, but ultimately you want `<input name="name="user_item[user_item_images_attributes][picture][]"`. It sounds like the `<input>` is missing the initial `user_item` part.

Comment: Ok now with that change I am getting `=>{"item_id"=>"3", "user_item_images_attributes"=>{}}`.  Is something still wrong though since the hash is empty while typing params shows all the info for the files?

Comment: You answered my question, I'll make a new question to address these additional concerns.